# How to Stop Previously Playing Ringtone in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I am trying to handle the notifications ringtone. For now, i am playing the ringtone on button click. Whenever i click the button after first attempt, i need to stop the previously playing ringtone and start the new one. But m not able to do it.

Here is my code :

```
RingtoneManager  manager = new RingtoneManager(this);
Ringtone ringtone = manager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            manager.setStopPreviousRingtone(true);
            ringtone.play();
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (ringtone.isPlaying())
                        ringtone.stop();
                }
            }, 30000);
```

but this is not working.

Here is my Complete Code :

```
RingtoneManager manager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pickMediaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickMediaButton);
    manager = new RingtoneManager(this);
    manager.setStopPreviousRingtone(true);
    pickMediaButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 5);

        }
    });

}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {

    String chosenRingtone = null;

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 5)
    {
        Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

        if (uri != null)
        {
            chosenRingtone = uri.toString();
            Ringtone ringtone = manager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri);

            ringtone.play();
            /*  final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (ringtone.isPlaying())
                        ringtone.stop();
                }
            }, 30000);*/
        }
        else
        {
            chosenRingtone = null;
        }
    }       

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, chosenRingtone+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to use a *RingtoneManager*-instance in your use-case.

Just obtain a *Ringtone* by *RingtoneManager.getRingtone(Context, Uri)* and set it to a member. Before obtaining a new ringtone, check if you previously started a Ringtone and stop it in case it is playing.

```
private Ringtone ringtone;

public void method(...) {
    if (ringtone != null) ringtone.stop();
    ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
    ringtone.play();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this by instantiating RingtoneManager in my on create method. But its not working too.

Comment: Its stoping, but not picking up the ringtone of my selection...its picking by default selected tone every time whatever i pick

Comment: this is my Uri :  content://media/external/audio/media/3650

Comment: Ok, when using Ringtone-Picker (ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER) there is no reason to use a RingtoneManager-Instance in your code.